# SwiftUI - How to draw border around scaled to fit NSImage

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui

I have an image that is scaled to the width/height of the current window. I need to draw a border around the image. I have tried the below code, however, it doesn't draw an exact border around the image (see screenshots attached). What am I missing?

```
import SwiftUI

struct RectangleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ZStack {
                Image("front")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 400, height: geo.size.height)
                    .clipShape(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    )
                    .overlay(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .stroke(lineWidth: 10).foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    )
            }
            .padding()
            .position(x:geo.frame(in:.global).midX,y:geo.frame(in:.global).midY)
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the code in my view controller.

```
import Cocoa
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let rectangleView = RectangleView()
        let contentView = NSHostingController(rootView: rectangleView)
        let rectView = contentView.view
        rectView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(rectView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            rectView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectView.superview!.leadingAnchor),
            rectView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectView.superview!.trailingAnchor),
            rectView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectView.superview!.topAnchor),
            rectView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rectView.superview!.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

}
```

[image: Incorrect border around image1]

[image: Incorrect border around image2]

Answer (score 0):

you have given a static frame for the Image  `.frame(width: 400, height: geo.size.height)`

So, you need to be specific about the aspect ratio.
Change the `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)` to `.aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)`

Comment: Using .fill is not a solution. I need the image to always maintain aspect ratio within the given width.